# While copying huge number of files from AWS S3 Bucket which files are copied first?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

While copying huge number of files from AWS S3 Bucket which files are copied first?
Suppose - from a single PREFIX location with `aws s3 cp` command.

Are they FIFO or just alphabetically or randomly? Can we control this?

Comment: No guarantee that I'm aware of. Obviously you could list the bucket and then copy individual objects or common-prefix objects in whatever order you like.

Comment: Why is the order important for you? Are you using S3 to trigger other events? I would think that the order is Alphabetical, but objects are copied in parallel and some might therefore be finished copying before earlier copies have completed.